Spyder console: Avoid empty lines in REPL output
I am using Anaconda's Spyder.  In the console, I want to see more of the historical output, including warnings/errors.  Since the Spyder uses IPython, I found from here that avoid the vertical white space by putting the following into the IPython config files: c.InteractiveShell.separate_in = ''.  From here, I found that the config file is c:/Users/User.Name/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py.  It didn't exist, so I created it with the one line above.  The Spyder console output still contains too much vertical white space.  What else can I try?
Example session
The messages for In[40] have a lot of empty lines while the message for In[41] is followed by empty lines.
In [40]:   dfLLnMsgColr = dfMsg[['lat_km','long_km','MMSI']] \
    ...:      .merge( dfMMSI[['MMSI','nMsg','MMSIcolr']] \
    ...:                 .rename(columns={'nMsg':'nMsgPrMMSI'}) )
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[40], line 2
    .merge( dfMMSI[['MMSI','nMsg','MMSIcolr']] \

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3767 in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5877 in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5941 in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "['nMsg', 'MMSIcolr'] not in index"


In [41]: 2 + \
    ...: # Test comment amidst many continued lines
  Cell In[41], line 2
    # Test comment amidst many continued lines
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [42]:


give some examples of the empty lines you are trying to get ride of.  In some cases the extra NL are  added by ipython itself, in others they might be part of the object's own formatting (as in numpy dimension separators).  In some cases they convey useful information, and can only be removed by post-formatting replacing 'nl nl' with 'nl'.

I added example output.  Thanks for the prompting.

Looks like most of the space is in the traceback and error message.  That probably isn't under the control of the ipython REPL. I haven't paid much attention to spacing in the qtconsole ipython that I usually use, except to toggle the %xmode setting if the traceback is too verbose.

@hpaulj: Thanks! I find it interesting that you say "qtconsole". I just thought of it as a text terminal, and Googling shows that Spyder does use QT (which I mentally associated with GUI widgets). That was just a detour, I did also looked into %xmode, with useful pages here and here.  I think I like %xmode plain and %xmode minimal. Much better than sys.tracebacklimit=0 and delattr(sys,"tracebacklimit").

@hpaulj: Did you want to post %xmode as the answer?  I mean, it's not really, but it certainly helps, and is about as good as can be.
